# Can you force stalemate with KB/K?

Tags: endgame, stalemate

Since the practical answer, pending the old suggestions to rate stalemate different, is "Who cares?", I doubt "official" [tablebases](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23196/tablebases-for-variant-where-stalemate-is-a-win) exist. (Since winning the KNN/KP endgame depends on partial stalemating, [for KN/K](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13120) we know an answer.) From my own experiments, I guess it's "no" for B, but as in the case of N, [danger zones](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13120) may exist. Does anyone have a surefire algorithm?

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13120
(which also refutes the guess that no such tablebase exists).
In particular, no, KN/K generally cannot force stalemate; 
many KNN/KP wins depend on the defending King having no access to
squares occupied by the pawn or controlled by the Knight blocking that pawn.

Comment: OK, I edit all in.